# Padding on the right goes off screen on window resize

Tags: css

Basically while I was making a website I noticed when I resized the window the padding on the right and bits of text is being pushed off the screen

How it is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/66TTN.png How it should be: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xLSdO.png

html:

```
<div id="l-ContentContainer">
    <div class="content content-divider">
        <h2>Article 1</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>

        <p>Integer laoreet diam eu interdum ornare...</p>

        <p>Pellentesque varius neque sed fermentum consectetur...</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.content {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
```

Any way to fix this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your div `content` takes the width of the body since you have given the width as 100%. Try using box-sizing to `content` div

```
.content {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    /* Firefox */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/xNrPq/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your div!

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

Comment: Didn't work, thanks for trying. edit: Nevermind this would have worked if I added -moz-box-sizing aswell, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First reconsider the 100% width and max-width in your implementation. Then apply a 10px padding to your paragraph tag not content. Try also using reset.css if you are not. You can design this structure better.

```
.content {
    max-width: 1000px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    padding:10px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your div is already filling the whole width of the container div, so just remove the `width: 100%` part. since you already set a max width of 1000px it won't damage your display.

Adding padding to an element increases its dimensions **after** the size was set, so your div width is actually 100% + 20px.